# What is the size of empty derived class in c++ and java?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have got some related answers like [Why the size of empty class that is derived from two empty classes is 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624706/why-the-size-of-empty-class-that-is-derived-from-two-empty-classes-is-2)  but not get the answer to my question clearly.

```
interface PI1
{
    default void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Default PI1");
    }
}

interface PI2
{
    default void show()
    {
        System.out.println("Default PI2");
    }
}

class TestClass implements PI1, PI2
{
    public void show()
    {
        PI1.super.show();
        PI2.super.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TestClass d = new TestClass();
        d.show();
    }
}
```

**Does this JAVA program show multiple inheritance?**

Comment: Stay away from interviews asking you these questions.

Comment: Every subobject must have a unique address + type combination. This rule allows an empty derived class to have size 1 in C++, with effectively size 0 for the base class object. This is known as the Empty Base Class optimization, or EBO optimization.

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`? The very concept of "size" of a class in Java is ill-defined and cannot be answered without detailed knowledge of the specific JVM version you're targeting.

Comment: I must say I don't understand what you find unclear exactly. I must also say that pulling both Java and C++ into this question is unlikely to end up being productive.

Comment: Rolled back. Please do not edit a question to be a completely different one. Instead, post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the minimum size is 1.

However, the other question is about multiple inheritance from base classes *of the same type*. Two objects of the same type cannot have the same address, because then they would not *be* different objects.

The address is an important part of the identity of an object.

So, if you have two objects of the same type, the minimum size would be 2.

None of this happens in Java, because there is no multiple inheritance.

Comment: The minimum is allowed to be 0 due to EBO: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2714e1b9db0dfab9

Comment: @NathanOliver - We are probably talking about different things. The minimum *total* size is 1, and `sizeof(any part)` will also never be less than 1. That the size of the whole object is not the sum of the sizes of the parts is not limited to his case.